# Import route from one rip group to another

Tags: routing, juniper, rip

Just started out with RIP implementation in juniper routers. Was not able to find much info on the following points. Any help is appreciated. I have defined 2 RIP groups, both in the same routing instance:

```
root@rip-host-re0# show protocols rip
group rip-group1 {
    export advertise-routes-through-rip;
    neighbor et-2/0/25:2.0;
}
group rip-group2 {
    neighbor et-2/0/25:3.0;
}
```

1. Do we have a command to check RIP routes for each rip group? I believe the RIP routes will get added to the inet.0 table, but how do I verify which rip group does the route belong to? Found a reference to `"show route protocol rip group rip-group1"` cli command by chatgpt, however I don't see it on my device.
2. Is it possible to import routes from one group to another. I found 2 possible solutions:
3. Define a policy and export it from group1

> set policy-options policy-statement EXPORT-TO-RIP2 term 1 from
> protocol rip-group rip-group1 
>  set policy-options policy-statement
> EXPORT-TO-RIP2 term 1 then accept 
>  set protocols rip group
> rip-group1 export EXPORT-TO-RIP2

Won't this just  re-advertise rip-group1 routes again via rip-group1? I don't see any references to rip-group2

4. Define a policy and import from group 2

> set policy-options policy-statement IMPORT-TO-RIP2 term 1 from protocol rip-group rip-group1 
> set policy-options policy-statement IMPORT-TO-RIP2 term 1 then accept 
> set protocols rip group rip-group2 import IMPORT-TO-RIP2

Will this be a more appropriate solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RIP Groups aren't routing-tables - think of them as a way to group connection-specific information (like different authentication types or export policies) for different sets of neighbours.  If all RIP neighbours are under your control, and you want to advertise the same routes to each neighbour, you can simply include all neighbour interfaces under a single group.

> Do we have a command to check RIP routes for each rip group? I believe the RIP routes will get added to the inet.0 table, but how do I verify which rip group does the route belong to? Found a reference to "show route protocol rip group rip-group1" cli command by chatgpt, however I don't see it on my device.

There isn't really a command to determine which routes are received from which group, but you can use:

```
show route receive-protocol rip <neighbour-ip-address>
```

to show routes received from a specific neighbour (useful if you have multiple neighbours on a single broadcast domain/VLAN), or otherwise, use:

```
show route protocol rip
```

since the interface for the next-hop of the route will also be the interface it was learnt on (the next-hop IP address will also be the IP address of the neighbour it was learnt from).

> Is it possible to import routes from one group to another.

By default RIP will import all received routes from any RIP neighbour into inet.0 - if you want to EXPORT routes learnt from neighbours in RIP Group A to neighbours in RIP Group B, just reference them in an EXPORT policy and attach that to RIP Group B.

Unless you have a reason for filtering specific routes from your updates, use something like:

```
set policy-options policy-statement RIP-ROUTES from protocol rip
set policy-options policy-statement RIP-ROUTES then accept
set protocols rip group rip-group1 export RIP-ROUTES
set protocols rip group rip-group2 export RIP-ROUTES
```

> set policy-options policy-statement EXPORT-TO-RIP2 term 1 from protocol  rip-group rip-group1

I'm not sure where you got the above configuration from (maybe ChatGPT?), but it is not valid Junos - specifically `from protocol rip-group` is not a valid match condition.